# Autoboot pi program issue (Raspberry Pi 4 , Python 3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi4

I currently am running a program through Thonny, and I want to make the pi autoboot that program whenever it turns on. I currently have the pi 4, and the code is run on Python3. Have tried many ways to autoboot such as using rc local, and bash rc, but none seem to work.

Comment: [pm2](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/quick-start/)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the `autostart` file.

Edit the following file:
`sudo nano /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart`

The default should look something like:

```
@lxpanel --profile LXDE-pi
@pcmanfm --desktop --profile LXDE-pi
@xscreensaver -no-splash
```

Add the command to run your script utilizing the @ prefix and save. The new `autostart` file should look like:

```
@lxpanel --profile LXDE-pi
@pcmanfm --desktop --profile LXDE-pi
@xscreensaver -no-splash
@python3 /home/pi/your_script.py
```

More info: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=294014

Comment: I tried this method, and when I save that. And then reboot the pie, it just starts up normally again, onto the desktop.

Comment: How do you know your script didn't execute? What are you trying to run?

Comment: I'm trying to run a thonny program, that when the pi starts up just runs the code. The code displays a blank image with a number box and gives you the ability to type in a number and the photo corresponding to that number will appear. I want the pi to go straight to that blank screen everytime you turn it on.

Comment: I'm somewhat confused. Is this a gui? Or are you trying to launch the script inside of Thonny?

Answer (score 0):

By using things like `.bashrc`, your program will only get executed when you open a command prompt or terminal.

You can use [`systemd` services](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html):

- create a file `your_service.service` in `/etc/systemd/system/` (you need to be root, so use `sudo`). The filename will be the name of your service, without the `.service` extension (in this case your service will be named `your_service`)
- put this in it (without the comments):

```
[Unit]
Description=A short description of your service
After=network.target # <-- put this if your script needs network, otherwise you can omit this line
StartLimitIntervalSec=0

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always # use this to always restart the script if the process ends. If your script only needs to run once at startup and is not a daemon, don't use this.
RestartSec=1
User=root # user account used to run the service
ExecStart=python3 /path/to/your/script.py

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then, you can start your script with this command:

```bash
sudo systemctl start your_service
```

You can finally enable the service to be run automatically at startup with this command:

```bash
sudo systemctl enable your_service
```

You can find more documentation / tutorials on systemd services and on all the available options in the following links:

- https://medium.com/@benmorel/creating-a-linux-service-with-systemd-611b5c8b91d6
- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-systemctl-to-manage-systemd-services-and-units
- https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html
- https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Systemd

Comment: Any commands within `.bashrc` are also executed on reboot.